# What is the path cost parameter used in AODV protocol route selection in XBee S2 (XB24-B) modules?

Tags: routes, protocols, network-protocols, zigbee

My question is whether Hop count or RSSI(Received Signal Strength Indicator) is used in route selection criterion in XBee Series 2 (XB24-B) mesh enabled modules which uses AODV routing protocol while establishing route?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question, but seems like something best answered by the product manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

The XBee radios appear to use hop count for AODV, but support Many-to-One Routing and Source Routing options that could make use of RSSI instead.  For details, start with this [Digi Developer Wiki Page on Large ZigBee Networks](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Large_ZigBee_Networks_and_Source_Routing), and then perhaps read more about those features in the documentation for the modules you're using.